# Show file edited in git log

Tags: git, logging

I'm using this to generate a detailed log with date:

```
git log --pretty --since="2014-10-20"

commit 7fa4e9c196b29d925b33aff3c85a98f53248e77b
Author: a_coder <a_coder@example.com>
Date:   Wed Nov 26 07:58:49 2014 -0500

feedCat tests ok
```

The output does not include the file being edited.  Is there a way to add this?  I tried `-p`, but this includes file contents and diff.  I'm just looking for the file/script name right now.

Is this possible in git log?

Answer (score -1):

I know, that if you use

```
git show <commithash>
```

that you can show the file(s) affected by the commit. Not sure if you can do this with git log though

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but would like to hear why this is a bad answer from whoever did the downvoting - for education's sake.